# Does Microsoft Graph Files API really allow to fix a file name after unsuccessful upload?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

[Microsoft API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-beta) states that it is possible to get an error at the end of a file upload in case the file name already exists and offers a method to resolve the issue by providing new name when making PUT request to the URL similar to one that creates upload session.

I was unable to make use of this approach to recover because once I get the error the session does not seem to valid any more. It's applicable both to personal and business accounts while the error messages and the behavior is slightly different.

**Creating session**

```
POST drives/{driveId}/items/{folderId}:/filename.txt:/createUploadSession
{
  "item": {
    "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior" : "fail",
    "name" : "filename.txt"
  }
}
```

Response

```
{
    "expirationDateTime": "2022-10-15T11:03:51.568Z",
    "nextExpectedRanges": ["0-"],
    "uploadUrl": "{uploadUrl}"
}
```

**Uploading bytes**

```
PUT {uploadUrl}
```

Response

```
Status 409
{
    "error": {
        "code": "nameAlreadyExists",
        "message": "An item with the same name already exists under the parent"
    }
}
```

**Fixing file name**

```
PUT drives/{driveId}/items/{folderId}:/filename~01.txt
{
    "@microsoft.graph.sourceUrl": "{uploadUrl}",
    "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior" : "fail",
    "name" : "filename~01.txt"
}
```

Response for personal

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "itemNotFound",
        "message": "Upload session not found",
        "innerError": {
            "code": "uploadSessionNotFound"
        }
    }
}
```

Response for business:

```
Status 400
{
    "error": {
        "code": "invalidRequest",
        "message": "@content.sourceUrl can only contain a data uri."
    }
}
```

**Accessing upload session**

```
GET {uploadUrl}
```

Response (for personal)

```
{
    "expirationDateTime": "2022-10-15T11:03:51.568Z",
    "nextExpectedRanges": []
}
```

Response (for business)

```
Status 404
{
    "error": {
        "code": "itemNotFound",
        "message": "The upload session was not found"
    }
}
```

How to fix this appropriately?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the upload session is terminated when the commit fails due to name conflict. That means you won't be able to retry the commit with a new name unfortunately.

One thing you could do is to use the `rename` conflict behavior, and upon completion if the name isn't what you expected you can assume conflict and send a rename request to your backup name. It may also be that the name chosen by the service is adequate (basically just puts a number before the extension) in which case you don't need to do anything else.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Brad! That could be an option but it consumes an extra call to Graph reducing quota. What I would really like to see is the issue filed in MS backlog with a hope that it could be resolved in reasonable terms. Although I am not really sure that MS experts noticed my post.

Comment: In this kind of recovery scenario an RT would be required anyway. Thinking it through more, "fail" may still leave the "~01.txt" file around for this kind of failure so you could recover with a manual rename, but that's not really much different to my original proposal. What would your ideal solution for this scenario look like?

Comment: At present I use default renaming strategy provided by Microsoft, that produces "fileName 1", "fileName 2" copies of a given existing "fileName". But there have been some circumstances that nudge to make an attempt to get this under control. So, ideally, I would prefer to have Microsoft to follow their specification and allow me to perform some operations with a not completed upload session. (interestingly, that deferring commit does not help here and works pretty the same way) That would let the app consume less API calls quota and provided more flexibility.

Comment: Definitely, there are some alternative strategies and they would work fine if the main goal was to control drive items naming, but this is not the case. So, what I am looking for now is a kind of confirmation that there is an issue on MS end and make them fix the issue if there is one. Than you, Brad, for your effort spent with me on the issue!